# How to only exclude directories in specific places from rsync, and not all directories with a particular name?

Tags: rsync

rsync lets you exclude directories like .cache and lost+found when making backups of your home partition. That's great, except it does it for all directories with those names. How can I only exclude /home/lost+found and /home//.cache, and not any others? I doubt I have any other directories named .cache, but still, it's definitely a bad solution otherwise.

Comment: Just specify the directories you want to exclude with their full path. eg `/home/user/.cache` If that gets a bit unwieldy use the option to exclude a list that you create in a file

Comment: It is not that rsync exclude option would exclude all the directories specified, by name, but only the directories in relative path of the backed up directory.